# swift + keystone user / password invalid

Tags: php, openstack, openstack-swift, keystone

i am newbie at openstack
i just installed and configured Swift. 
Followed this instruction: http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/development_saio.html

everything works fine. Next i want to create users, groups dynamically. But i found its not possible by swift alone, but keystone. I read lots about keystone before install it, because i've never heard keystone.

my swift username and password is admin:admin, then i exported OS_USERNAME=admin,OS_PASSWORD=admin. But it always shows user/ password invalid error when i try to use keystone api or functions. How can i know Openstack user information or Keystone user information ?

is there any other way to manage user, groups, containers ?

My Goal is: creating cloud storage service. Manage all groups, users and storage limits by some back end app. it will be written in PHP, i hope php + curl can manage it.

plus one thing is very unclear, How do i create private files, and how clients access to this private files.

Please help me experts. I am very confused, spent 50 hours straight. Really stacked on it :(

Answer (score 0):

Openstack uses different credentials for each service, you can look at /etc/keystone/keystone.conf for the administration token and then set OS_SERVICE_TOKEN = {TheAdminToken}.

> [DEFAULT]
>
> admin_token = password

```
export OS_SERVICE_TOKEN = password
```

This way you got a easy access for local administration of keystone (Don't do this in an non-trusted network).

The next step it's to create the users and assign them a role in a tenant, wich can be do by curl or the keystone client.

After that, the last things it's to configure swift to connect to the keystone endpoint to the authentication task.

```
 swift -V2 -A http://keystone_endpoint_url:5000/v2.0 -U user -K pass -T tenant stat
```

To create your own php client you'll have to learn the APIs of both services.